# How to create objects based on a list in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have named a class "File", where there are some "attributes" as properties.

```
 class File
    {
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute3 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute4 { get; set; }

    }
```

The Text-files that I want to read, contains these "attributes".
For Example I have read files, and file names are like below:

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            filenames.Add("A0A01M");
            filenames.Add("A1G4AA");
            filenames.Add("A1L4AR");
            filenames.Add("A1L4AX");
    ...(more than 3000 Files)
```

How to crate class objects based on this list for each text files, which contains attributes ?!
I am a little bit confused here!!

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of the attributes. Show an example content of a file

Comment: How does the `File` class relate to the list? It's unclear.

Comment: Well, split this problem into two parts: 1) Reading/writing a single file; 2) Using the result of 1 in a loop or using LINQ to handle multiple files. Which part are you stuck on at the moment?

Comment: so you could create instances of `File` using `new File { Attribute1 = "A1...", Attribute2 = "A2..." }`...

Comment: @MaartenDev I get the feeling that the attributes are text inside the file, which probably means this question will be closed as a duplicate/relative of "how do i read a CSV file in C#?"

Comment: Ah yes, seems like CSV indeed, OP should clarify the input

Comment: I have added the List just as example. So, I have 3000 Text-files, and based on there names I want to create Class Objects and to save "attributes" (like: name, id, revision) at the class properties for each file...

Comment: Did you checkout using something like `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes, the problem is not HOW TO GET AND READ FILES? but HOW TO SAVE AS CLASS OBJECTS EACH FILE AND EACH ATTRIBUTE!

Comment: No need to type in CAPS, that won't help you getting an answer

Comment: @MaartenDev Ok, thanks =)

Comment: *to save "attributes" (like: name, id, revision)* - So, where does "name" come from? Where does "ID" come from? Where does "revision" come from? You need to put some data in your properties (attributes, in your terms).. But you haven't said where this data comes from

Comment: So with each filename you want to create an instace of file class no? , then you have add the file class a constructor to add the instance of the object with specific id , is this what you need, i can write the code if this is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
List<File> files = filenames.Select(CreateFile).ToList();
```

and a method `CreateFile`:

```
static File CreateFile(string fileName)
{
    // probably load the file from disc here and extract attributes
    return new File
    {
        Attribute1 = ...,
        Attribute2 = ...,
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: I think this solutions is not the best option , you dont use filename for nothing, I think the filename attribute has to be on File class.

Comment: @hesolar: my comment in `CreateFile` suggests that OP needs to use the fileName to load that file from disc. But the implementation is up to OP and out of scope of this question. I guess the `fileName` is not part of the `File` class(but it's easy to add it as additional property). He wants to initialize 5 attributes from the content of each file.

Answer (score 0):

First add constructor with a id:

```
class File
    {
        public File(String id){this.ID=id;}
        public string ID {get; set;}
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute3 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute4 { get; set; }

    }
```

Then on your main method where you get the filename list you can do that:
List filenames....
Create a empty list of files:

```
List<File> fileList = new List<File>();
```

Then fill fileList with the other values of the filenames list

```
filenames.ForEach(filenameID=> fileList.Add(filenameID);
```